# Force ng-strict-di globally not just on an ng-app level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm trying to add ng-strict-di (to help throw errors anytime DI isn't done correctly for a controller/directive/etc).

I have a `globalApp module` containing miscellaneous helper directives / httpInterceptors etc. Is it possible to add it there somehow?

I found this solution, but this module never gets bootstrapped to the page, *it's simply Injected into a child Module on a page*.

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['globalApp'], {
   strictDi: true
});
```

But this simply breaks, since the page is already bootstrapped with an `ng-app="app"` on each specific page using angular.

How else can this be achieved?

Comment: How is twitter-bootstrap tag related to your question?

Comment: Fixed that sorry, it added it in there! @mxa055

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `ng-strict-di` to the app, it forces all of the app's dependencies (that are used) to be explicitly annotated.

So, if you have:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <foo></foo>
</body>
```

with `foo` defined in another module and without explicit annotation:

```
anotherModule.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    template: "{{foo}}",
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.foo = "foo"; // $scope is not explicitly annotated
    }
  };
});
```

then this would throw an error.

In other words, you don't need to add `ng-strict-di` per module - just on the app that uses the services, controllers, directives, etc... in that module.

Comment: So there's no way to globally have this on everywhere without having to add it manually per page?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS, what is "globally"? What's more global than at the app-level? Sure, you could have multiple apps per index.html, but that is a rare case with little benefits

Comment: Yeah true, I guess I just meant within this globalApp module that each page injects. But you're right, ng-app is as global as it gets :)

Comment: Just a side note you don't need to DI controller/link within directives, those params have to be in a specific order you can name them whatever! It doesn't throw an error on this one, but it would if it was a `.service()` lets say

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS, I mean, I think I understand that what you wanted is to have strict DI enforced on a module, regardless of whether an app that uses the module has DI. But, then it doesn't make much sense, since the app would break if it was minified without explicit DI.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS, the `link` function has an order of well-defined parameters. the `controller` function gets injected. Here's how it breaks: http://plnkr.co/edit/AdGWuHfqmDRgz5ASN1bg?p=preview